# How to progmmatically trigger menu item click event in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a sub in vb.net written below.It's called when a menu item is clicked. How can I programmatically call this sub.

```
Private Sub SetNewToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SetNewToolStripMenuItem.Click

End Sub
```

Comment: You mean you want to use [SetNewToolStringMenuItem.PerformClick()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.menuitem.performclick(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Create a method to do whatever you want (that does nothing), then call it directly and from that method.  Events are for getting input from users.

Comment: `SetNewToolStripMenuItem_Click(Nothing, EventArgs.Empty)`

Comment: @LarsTech Thanks, That Works

Answer (score 1):

Just put the stuff you want to do in another method which can be called from either place.

```
Private Sub SetNewToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SetNewToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Foo()
End Sub

Private Sub Foo()
    ' do stuff in here
End Sub

Private Sub Bar()
    Foo()
End Sub
```

But be careful if calling `Foo()` from a non-UI thread. If it's possible, you may consider invoking the call to the UI thread when required.

```
Private Sub Foo()
    If SetNewToolStripMenuItem.Owner.InvokeRequired Then
        SetNewToolStripMenuItem.Owner.Invoke(New Action(AddressOf Foo))
    Else
        ' do stuff in here
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But  LarsTech mentioned a direct call as a comment to my question. 

        `SetNewToolStripMenuItem_Click(Nothing, EventArgs.Empty)`

This works